# Java Play 2 error: reference to unauthorized is ambiguous

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

After I imported a java play 2 app i get a runtime exception of

```
both method ok(Content) in Results and method ok(JsonNode) in Results match
[error] ReportStatusController.java:40: error: reference to ok is ambiguous
[error]             return ok(responseWrapper.generateResponse(Status.UNAUTHORIZED, "Invalid Token"));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Show us the signature of the `generateResponse` method

Comment: Think we'll need to see the content of the generateResponse method here. It seems unusual to be returning an ok response, yet it's passing in an UNAUTHORIZED status to this method. There is an unauthorized() method for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It means that there are two functions in scope that are called `ok` and can accept the argument. Try to refer the function in a fully qualified name, or remove imports.

BTW - 
Did you mean `Ok(...)` (note capital `O`)?

Comment: Lower case ok is correct in the Play framework to return a 200 status and content to the view.

Comment: `Ok` (with an upper-case O) is what you find in the Scala API.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved the issue finally...
The problem was the my JAVA_HOME system variable was not set and i almost certain the play application used java 8. When i set the JAVA_HOME variable to java 7 path the app run without errors.